# call ajax function automatically

Tags: javascript, php

I have a dynamically generated post, where i use ajax to find, the no of comments and likes in it. so, i gave a onmouseovr selector and called the js function. but i want it to automatically be called once every 2 seconds. how should i do it?

```
echo "</div>";

//the div has to be updated every 2-3 seconds.
//but i dont know how. so, i gave a mouseoverfunction.

echo '<div onmouseover="yopahshareloader(';
echo "'" .$id. "',";
echo "'" .$postype. "'";
echo ');" id="'.$id.'_action" style="height:20px;width:100%;margin-bottom:5px;overflow:hidden;">' ;
echo '</div>';
```

Comment: setTimeout(function(){ function_name(); }, 2000);

Comment: @fees `setTimeout` calls the function once, not repeatedly

Comment: but, what if there are arguments for the function? do i still do the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setInterval)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.setInterval(function() {
        yopahshareloader('<?php echo $id; ?>', '<?php echo $postype; ?>');
    }, 2000);
</script>
```

Comment: what you gave would be correct if only a single div has to be updated. but there are many divs, its like a social networking site. and number posts could be anything. so, i have to call the function for each post individually. :\

Comment: I see. Then just add a php foreach look around the function name above then, echoing out the different $ids/$postypes. Without seeing more of your code, it will be hard to give a complete example.