# How to update web page content like facebook news feed update

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to create a web page that can update data automatically calling ajax method. But ajax method need to call by user. There is no process that can always try to find any update of this web page. I want to update data like chat box when Data update on my server. Now I notice that Facebook news feed automatic update. I want to make like this.

Comment: Maybe are you looking for something like [socket.io](http://socket.io)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `setInterval`

```
window.setInterval(function() {
         ...  ajax call ....
    }, 2000);
```

[call ajax function automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26954325/1226748)

Comment: Try above code first before asking something else .

Comment: It works, Thanks `jimmy obonyo`

Comment: Welcome , Kindly mark prefered answer as accepted to help others in future , also edit your question to be to point to prevent it from being flagged !

Answer (score 2):

Ajax methods don't need to be called by the user; you're free to call them whenever you like from your Javascript code.

One simple possibility would be to make use of Javascript's setTimeout() or setInterval() functions which can run whatever Javascript you like (including Ajax calls) after a set time interval.

Alternatively then you could look at newer technology like WebSockets https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket to help reduce load on the server and browser.